# Unclosed group near index 1

Tags: javascript, regex, search

Somebody can help me with this function on javascript?

i did this function above on javascript, but when i try to use on this string: **Item 1 – 1 X 500 OS 129062.
MATERIAL DE NOSSA PROPRIEDADE QUE SEGUE P/ ANALISE E TESTE, SEM DÉBITO
(AMOSTRA GRÁTIS).**

I get a error: Unclosed group near index 1

Plz, help me

```
function retiraAcentos(texto) {

  var caracEspec = '.áàãâäéèêëíìîïóòõôöúùûüçñÁÀÃÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÕÖÔÚÙÛÜÇÑ/';
  var caracComum = '.aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucnAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUCN.';
  var textoResultado = '';
  for (i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {

    var letra = texto.substr(i, 1);
    if ((letra == "*") || (letra == "?") || (letra == "\n") || (letra == '+')) {
      continue;
    }

    var posLetra = caracEspec.search(letra);    

    if (posLetra >= 0) {      
      textoResultado += caracComum.substr(posLetra, 1);
    } else {
      textoResultado += letra;
    }

  }

  return textoResultado;

}
```

Comment: Error happens on such example input: `"foobar".search("(")`. See @x-ray answer for explanation.

Comment: I think the problem is the `search` function since is takes a regular expression. And definitely the single `(` is an unclosed group. Better use the `indexOf` alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) function expects a regular expression. Try using `indexOf` instead:

```
var posLetra = caracEspec.indexOf(letra);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some research using *jsfiddle*.

It turns out that if a text contains a parenthesis (opening or closing),
then such a parenthesis at some point becomes the argument of `search`
function and it raises *unterminated parenthetical* error.

Apparently this function uses regex internally and a single parenthesis
is not any valid regex.

Use `indexOf` instead of `search`.

Another correction: Remove dot char from the beginning of `caracEspec`
and `caracComum`.

If you used `search` then the dot (treated as regex) matched **any** char,
in this case the first char from `caracEspec`, giving `posLetra` = 0.
This resulted in taking the 1st char from `caracComum` (fortunately, also a dot).

Now these combinations are not needed.